# Accessing model attributes from module method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know there are some gems out there that give you slugs out of the box. However, I think doing something similar is a good way of learning.

Since I'm using slugs in several models, I decided to create a module and include it via ActiveSupport::Concern.

This is my module `sluggable.rb`:

```
module Sluggable
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    module ClassMethods
        def slug(*atts_to_slug)
            after_validation set_slug(atts_to_slug)
        end

        def set_slug(atts)
            slug_string = atts.map{|f| f.parameterize}.join("-")
            # Then I would think I can do something like:
            # model_instance.send("slug", slug_string)
        end
    end
end
```

Then I'd like to do something like this in the model:

```
class Classification < ApplicationRecord
    include Sluggable

    slug :name, :street
end
```

The problem I'm finding is:

How do I set the model's attribute `slug` from the module?

Answer (score 1):

`after_validation` is a callback that expects a method name, block or a callable object (proc/lambda).

The way you're currently using it. It will call `set_slug` once when `slug` is first called and not after that.

`slug` should set the required attributes into some (class-level) variable. `after_validation` should call the `set_slug` method that should be an instance method. Then in the `set_slug` instance method you have access to all the attributes.

```
module Sluggable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def slug(*atts_to_slug)
      @atts_to_slug = atts_to_slug
    end

    def atts_to_slug
      @atts_to_slug
    end
  end

  included do # instance scope
    after_validation :set_slug

    def set_slug
      slug_string = self.class.atts_to_slug.map do |f|
        # send since we're in the instance and I want to just call `name`
        public_send(f).parameterize
      end.join("-")
      self.slug = slug_string
    end
  end
end
```